# Using C#, how can I extract all the HTML tags from a RichTextBox control?

Tags: c#, html, string, richtextbox

I have some html code in a `RichTextBox` in the text format. I need to extract all the `HTML` tags in the `RichTextBox` using C#. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You need to give a little more details on what you are trying to achive: extracting in Javascript, C#, etc... I guess C# by your tags but it's not straight-forward

Comment: In C#, i need to extract.

Comment: Are you working with Web Form or Win Form?

Comment: Win form application(RichTextBox).

Comment: Here is a link from SO,  [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) may show directions you can take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your first question, IF the HTML code is inside the RichTextBox, as per [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you simply need to read the Text property.

I guess that your request is slightly different, being how to get the HTML version of the the text in RTF format edited in RichTextBox.
If so, the answer is: there is no unique way to do it. You have different options

- Buy a library as DevExpress which has an HTML TextBox
- Write your own parser according to your needs (eventually starting with one the many attempts in the internet)

Comment: Ok Mauro, Actually i am developing an app like Microsoft Expression web. i am struggling at showing the property of the selected html tag in the richtextbox.